# BusyIndicator not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight busyindicator not working properly.My isssue is i'm using multipage.On page change i call adapter for webservice and call busy indicator so that it show work in progress while fetching.but what happen is page change and indicator show and hide quickly but adpater still in fetching phase and after sometime data called successfully but during these working no busy indicator shows.

```
var busyIndicator = null;

function wlCommonInit(){
    busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator();
    }
```

This is the code i call on page change.

```
    busyIndicatorDemo();
    var viewPath = "views/add_fund_transfer.html";
    WL.Page.load(viewPath,
        {
                onComplete: function() {    

                PayAnyOne_Controller.GetBranches(GetBranchesProcedureName);
                busyIndicator.hide();

                }
            });

function busyIndicatorDemo() {
    busyIndicator.show();
    setTimeout(15000);
}
```

its seems like busyindicator doesn't work with adpater when using in multipage.
Please give me the solution or the problem in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem is in the flow of the code. you're running this code basically:

1. show busy indicator
2. load page
3. when page has finished loading: invoke procedure (**async call**), and hide busyindicator.

So this generates the behavior you've reported - the busyindicator is shown and quickly hidden once the page has finished loading, even though the service is still fetching data (in an async call)

moving the busyindicator.hide to the onSuccess of the invoke procedure should solve the problem (put it also in the onFailure ...)
Hope this helps

Comment: above give solution some how worked..but its happening now when i call the procedure busyindicator shows for few seconds and then disapear while the procedure still busy. i have done the above given solution.